# How to convert byte array of PDF to byte array of jpg image in Java using apache pdfbox api?

Tags: java, apache, file-io, pdfbox

I have been assigned this task in my project. I am getting byte array of PDF from a service and I have to convert it into byte array of JPG image and return byte array of JPG. Can anyone help me out please?

I tried below solution that is converting PDF byte array to JPG but not returning byte array of JPG.

```
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

import org.apache.pdfbox.util.PDFImageWriter;

import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;

public class DocumentService{
    public byte[] convertPDFtoImage(byte[] bytes) {
        InputStream targetStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        PDDocument document = null;
        try {
            document = PDDocument.load(targetStream);
            PDFImageWriter writer = new PDFImageWriter();
            writer.writeImage(document, "jpg", null, 1, 2, "C:\\Shailesh\\aaa");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error(e.getMessage(), e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: A Google search for something like "Java convert PDF to JPG" seems like the obvious place to start.

Comment: I have edited my question to make it more specific and clearer. Could anyone please suggest a solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found one solution but renderer.renderImageWithDPI(pageNumber, 300) method takes **page number as method argument** and it can **convert only one page of PDF at a time**. But I need **full PDf into JPG** in form of byte array.

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
import org.apache.pdfbox.rendering.PDFRenderer;

public class DocumentService {

    public byte[] convertPDFtoImage(byte[] bytesPDF) {
        InputStream targetStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytesPDF);
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        PDDocument document = null;
        try {
            document = PDDocument.load(targetStream);
            PDFRenderer renderer = new PDFRenderer(document);
            int pageNumber = 1;
            BufferedImage bi = renderer.renderImageWithDPI(pageNumber, 300);
            ImageIO.write(bi, "jpg", baos);
            baos.flush();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error(e.getMessage(), e);
        } finally {
            if (document != null) {
                try {
                    document.close();
                    baos.close();
                    log.info("End convert PDF to Images process");
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    log.error(e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        }
        return baos.toByteArray();
    }
}
```